# How can I clean chia seeds?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning, seeds, chia

I'm wondering about how to properly clean chia seeds since they cannot be washed in water as other seeds.

I've read that they need not to be washed, but then how to clean them?

Comment: Why do you believe they need to be cleaned?

Comment: @dbmag9 Because that's what one does before cooking or eating seeds. For example soy or sesame seeds.

Comment: I've never washed a seed in my life. First I've heard of it.

Comment: If you buy a bag of prepared seeds you don't need to clean them as that's already done. Washing them is a great way to ruin them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three main methods of cleaning dry seed:

1. Blow on it with a fan to remove chaff, dust and some leaf bits.
2. Sieve it to remove both the stuff that's too course or too fine.
3. Run it slowly down an inclined plane, like a breadboard. Seeds tend to bounce, crud doesn't and will stick to the board.